How to keep data frame data types when exporting to CSV file?
I have a pandas data frame with int64 , string[python] , and float64 data types. How do I preserve those data types when exporting pandas DataFrame.to_csv option?
I need the exported Excel file to be in CSV, but everytime I save it, the string column is not saved as string format.
I tried multiple solutions:

current_fleet_df['ID'] = current_fleet_df['ID'].astype(pd.StringDtype())
current_fleet_df['ID'] = current_fleet_df['ID'].astype(str)
current_fleet_df['ID'] = current_fleet_df['ID'].astype('str')
current_fleet_df['ID'] = current_fleet_df['ID'].astype('string')
then
current_fleet_df.to_csv('Current_Fleet.csv', index=False)

none of these solutions yielded the required result, being having the ID column saved in str format.

You can't, there is no concept of dtypes in CSV

The problem is not with how you save, but in how you read it. CSV doesn't keep data type. It's just a plain text file.
Everything you tried works in python only. After you save it into a CSV file, you have only text values separated by some delimiters.

thank you all for your comments, to give more context, I am participating in a competition where we have to submit a CSV file only, the system gives me an error that the "ID" column is not of type string, but again, they also require submission to be in CSV format, does this mean it's their fault for specifying CSV as the only submission format?

Do you also submit the code that will read the CSV? Do you have a link to the competition for more details?

no, I don't, the link is below (though I am not sure if you might need to sign in to see the details), see constraints 15 & 2, as well as the first few lines of the "Evaluation" section.
https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/competitive/shellai-hackathon-2024/machine-learning/fleet-transition-challenge-9-975cec9c/

I don't want to create an account there just to see details, but it seems that they expect the ID to be in a specific format which includes letters. If that's the case, reading such a file will automatically set the type of the column to str/object.
Don't you have a sample_submission.csv file or something?

I do, tho I don't know what to look for in it exactly, or how to share it with you if that's needed.

https://www.shell.com/what-we-do/digitalisation/collaboration-and-open-innovation/shell-ai-hackathon-for-sustainable-and-affordable-energy.html is this the challenge they use? If so, I think that ID is just a concatenation of fuel type, vehicle size and year.
